# Set Object name for variable value

Tags: javascript

I am curious if it is possible to set the name of an object in Javascript to a variable value. So if I declare a variable objectName and want to create a new object whose name is the value of objectName.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example of how you imagine it would work? The description is little vague.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @Slam, thats perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var objectName = "myObjectName";

window[objectName] = {
    foo: "bar"
};

console.log(myObjectName); // { foo: 'bar'}
```

All global variables are properties of the window object, and since window is an object, we can create a dynamic property using `[]` syntax. And then you can access it as `window.myObjectName`, `window["myObjectName"]`  or just plain `myObjectName`

More info of window object here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp  and here https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/window

Comment: Don't use this. Don't create global variables.